# Creating a class based on user input

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and just had a quick question when writing a program that asks a user to create a playlist of their favorite songs!

```
class Playlist

array_songs = Array.new
print "How many songs do you want to add to your playlist? "
songs = gets.to_i

for i in 1..songs
    print "Enter song #{i}: "
    song = gets.chomp

    print "Enter genre for song #{i}: "
    genre = gets.chomp

    print "Enter artist of song #{i}: "
    artist = gets.to_i

    p = playlist.new
    p.set_song(song)
    p.set_genre(genre)
    p.set_artist(artist)
    array_songs << p
end
end 

puts "This is your current playlist: "

for song in array_songs
    puts "#{song.get_song} #{song.get_genre} #{song.get_artist}" 
end
```

So basically every time I run this, it won't work, saying I have undefined methods and such... Just want a few tips on how to make this work so that at the end of a user entering the songs, the result of all the songs will be printed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a misunderstanding of what a class is, or at least, how to use them well.

A class is a type of object which represents a distinct concept or item in the internal universe of the application.

The internal universe of an application like Stack Overflow consists of (amongst other things) `User`, `Question` and `Answer` objects. Therefore, these are some of the classes you might find in the source code.

An individual `Answer`, like this one, or an individual `User`, like you, is an instance of the class. It has its own distinct data, which is different to that of another `User` or `Answer`, but it shares the same behaviour, such as `delete` or `edit`.

You have a class called `Playlist`. Logically, this should be a list of `Song`s. As a `Song` is a separate concept, with its own data and behaviour, it should be a separate class.

Because a `Playlist` does not do anything at the moment, it's probably best to use an `Array` object. So that you can change this in the future, you can do something like this:

```
Playlist = Array
```

And later:

```
class Playlist
  # extra behaviour when needed
end
```

A `Song` has three pieces of data:

- `name`
- `genre`
- `artist`

In Ruby, we can use `attr_accessor` to handle the setters and getters.

```
class Song
  attr_accessor :name, :genre, :artist
end
```

Notice the case sensitivity on the class and variable names. You made that mistake with `p = playlist.new`.

Here is the fully adapted version of the code. I have changed some of the variable names to improve readability.

I have also changed your `for` loop to Ruby's `.times` method, which I feel is easier to read.

Finally, I have changed the `gets.to_i` for `artist` to `gets.chomp`, as I presumed it was supposed to be a `String` like the others. Just change it back if I was wrong about this.

```
Playlist = Array

class Song
  attr_accessor :name, :genre, :artist
end

songs = Playlist.new
print "How many songs do you want to add to your playlist? "
number_of_songs = gets.to_i

number_of_songs.times do |i|
  song_number = i + 1

  print "Enter song #{song_number}: "
  name = gets.chomp

  print "Enter genre for song #{song_number}: "
  genre = gets.chomp

  print "Enter artist of song #{song_number}: "
  artist = gets.chomp

  s = Song.new
  s.name   = name
  s.genre  = genre
  s.artist = artist

  songs << s
end

puts "This is your current playlist: "

songs.each do |song|
  puts "#{song.name} #{song.genre} #{song.artist}"
end
```

Lastly, I know that this does not apply to your case, but I feel it is important to learn if you did not know already: you can use `def` to add behaviour to a class. `attr_accessor` does this implicitly.

```
class Duck
  attr_accessor :name

  def quack
    "QUACK! My name is #{name}."
  end
end

a_duck = Duck.new
a_duck.name = "Mr. Duck"
puts a_duck.quack
#=> QUACK! My name is Mr. Duck.
```

Good luck.